# How to add an editable text box in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, text

I am looking to add a text-box onto my JPanel. This text box will be similar to something like in Microsoft PowerPoint: one that you can resize, move around, etc. I have looked into `JTextField` but I don't think this is what I need. I do **not** need a popup box like this:

[image]

I have a program that allows the user to add, resize and move shapes. I now want to be able to place a text box into these shapes. Here is an example of what I am looking for:

[image]

Is there anyway I can do this? Thanks.

Comment: Either handle the keyboard entry manually via a KeyListener, or just use a JTextArea or another text component.

Comment: A JTextArea is close to what I need. But I need it without a border and to display only the text. Is this possible?

Comment: Sure. Check out the API for useful methods, such as methods for setting the border.

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot, I'll definitely check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ComponentResizer](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/09/13/resizing-components/) class takes care of the resizing. Here is a working example for a resizeable JTextArea:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            buildGUI();
        }
    });
}

private static void buildGUI() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    ComponentResizer cr = new ComponentResizer();
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(null);
    f.add(mainPanel);

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("Some text\nSome other text");
    cr.registerComponent(textArea);

    mainPanel.add(textArea);
    textArea.setBounds(50, 50, 150, 150);

    f.setSize(400, 400);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

If you also want to move the JTextArea, you can use in addition [ComponentMover](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/) and add the following code:

```
    ComponentMover cm = new ComponentMover();
    cm.registerComponent(textArea);
    cm.setDragInsets( cr.getDragInsets() );
```

Comment: Thanks for the post! What import do I need for ComponentResizer?

Comment: You need to get the ComponentResizer java class from the link I posted, and put it into your project

Comment: DUH! Sorry, missed that :)